Error 'This process is unavailable or is configured incorrectly' in my inbox app (SAP ECC)
I am facing issue in configuring my inbox app. I have configured process inbox by following implementation documentation from FIORI app library.
I have a PO approval workflow which I am able to see in my inbox app as well but when I am clicking on open task button, I am getting error page

This process is unavailable or is configured incorrectly

Environment:

GBX01HR5
UIHR002

I have tried with SWFVISU configuration and some SAP notes but nothing works.
Kindly help me with the process to display PO details in my inbox app.
